# Problem getting data from function readDataAsURL(), returning undefined instead

Tags: angular, cordova, asynchronous, ionic-framework, base64

**Context**

I’m trying to receive an image file from my external storage as base64, to do this I’m using the function readAsDataURL(), that comes with the [Ionic File plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html), which is based in [File API](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). I don’t know what I’m doing wrong, because I can see the base64 string from the log inside the function, but I can’t return this string correctly, instead I’m receiving an undefined object.

---

**My Function**

```js
...    
this.uriToBase64(arrayItem2.filePath).then((imageAsBase64) => {
    console.log("image as base64: ", imageAsBase64); // Receiving undefined here
});
...
async uriToBase64(uri) {
    let nameFile = uri.replace(this.file.dataDirectory, '');

    await this.file.readAsDataURL(this.file.dataDirectory, nameFile).then((file64) => {
        let fileWithoutExtension = ('' + file64 + '').replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg|jpeg);base64,/, '');
        console.log("File without extension: ", fileWithoutExtension); // Receiving the base64 correctly here
        return fileWithoutExtension;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error while transforming image to base64: ", err);
    });     
}
```

---

**Details**

Ionic v4

I think the way I’m using the function is correct, we can see the same usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878272/cordova-file-plugin-readasdataurl-not-returning-file-data/42000326#42000326).

I found some related questions, but they don’t helped me much:

- [Problem with Ionic Capacitor, pretty similar to my problem](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1078)
- [Ionic storage problem, returning ZoneAwarePromise](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-get-the-localstorage-value-out-of-promise-scope-ionic-4/161492/4)
- [StackOverflow similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53504679/why-await-a-promise-doesnt-wait-the-promise-to-resolve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question answered [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-i-cant-get-data-from-function-readdataasurl-returning-a-promise-instead/172310/6?u=leonardofmed) by @aaronksaunders:

```
this.uriToBase64(arrayItem2.filePath).then((_result) => {
    console.log("image as base64: ", _result); // Receiving the  ZoneAwarePromise here
});
uriToBase64(uri) {
    let nameFile = uri.replace(this.file.dataDirectory, '');

    return this.file.readAsDataURL(this.file.dataDirectory, nameFile).then((file64) => {
        let base64String = ('' + file64 + '').replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg|jpeg);base64,/, '');
        console.log("data: ", base64String); // Receiving the base 64 correctly here
        return base64String;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error while transforming image to base64: ", err);
        return err;
    });     
}
```